# HTTP delete request in J2ME

Tags: http, java-me, midp

I'm trying to send an delete request on a Rails Server from J2ME

The output is

```
STATUS: 422
```

and the element is not deleted.

Here's the code:

```
    HttpConnection hc = null;
    InputStream istrm = null;
    String msg = "_method=DELETE";
    System.out.println(id);
    try {
        hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(server + "documents/" + id + ".xml");
        hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        hc.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hc.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "" + msg.getBytes().length);

        OutputStream out = hc.openOutputStream();
        out.write(msg.getBytes());
        out.close();

        System.out.println("STATUS: " + hc.getResponseCode()+ hc.getResponseMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following statements before closing outputstream

```
int res_code=hc.getResponseCode();
if(res_code==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
{
//Success
}
else
{
//Failure
}
.........
//After performing all operations then close streams and connection
out.close();
hc.close();
```

Try it.All the best